# How do I fix an immobilizer problem on a 2006 Kia Sedona?

Tags: electrical, ignition, kia, sedona

How do I fix a problem with my immobilizer? This is a follow up to this question: [2006 Kia Sedona intermittently not starting](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/2252/59)

What parts (if any) do I need?

What would be the best way to go about the repair?

Comment: Did you end up fixing this? If so, we'd love to hear back. Thanks!